How to add Custom header in https request with nginx proxy? Getting HTTP error code 400 from proxy
Add Custom header in https request with nginx proxy.
I am trying to use nginx as man in the middle proxy with ssl termination and add headers and send it to the same request host with updated headers
export https_proxy=http://localhost:8080
curl -v https://google.com

server {
    listen 8080 ssl;
     server_name localhost;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/mitm/nginx-mitm-proxy.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/mitm/nginx-mitm-proxy.key;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://$host$request_uri;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Custom-header "";
}

I am getting this error. curl: (56) Received HTTP code 400 from proxy after CONNECT

Nginx is probably the wrong tool for what you are trying to do. nginx cannot create dynamic certificates matching the target website as a proper MITM proxy would need to do - which means you'll get always certificate errors. nginx can also not handle CONNECT request without https://github.com/chobits/ngx_http_proxy_connect_module
